# Clickhouse fill empty rows with next non-empty value

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table like this

| date | id | price | desired previous value | desired next value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-08-17 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 2019-08-17 | 2 | 15.4 | 15.4 | 15.4 |
| 2019-08-18 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 5.6 |
| 2019-08-18 | 2 | 0 | 15.4 | 14 |
| 2019-08-19 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 5.6 |
| 2019-08-19 | 2 | 0 | 15.4 | 14 |
| 2019-08-20 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 5.6 |
| 2019-08-20 | 2 | 0 | 15.4 | 14 |
| 2019-08-21 | 1 | 5.6 | 5.6 | 5.6 |
| 2019-08-21 | 2 | 14 | 14 | 14 |

Its a result of this query:

```
SELECT a.date AS date,
       a.id AS id,
       p.price AS price
  FROM articles a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT date,
                    id,
                    price
               FROM prices) p
    ON a.date = p.date
   AND a.id = p.id
```

because prices table does not have data for all dates.
How can I fill zero price values with next or previous non zero value in clickhouse?

ver is 22.8.9.24

Comment: Please, edit your table in question with an additional column - the desired value for each row. Or explain the meaning of "next or previous non-zero value". "Next" in what group (if any) and order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH T AS 
(
SELECT c1 as date, c2 as id, c3 as price
FROM VALUES 
(
  (toDate ('2019-08-17'), 1, 5)     
, (toDate ('2019-08-17'), 2, 15.4)  
, (toDate ('2019-08-18'), 1, 0)     
, (toDate ('2019-08-18'), 2, 0)     
, (toDate ('2019-08-19'), 1, 0)     
, (toDate ('2019-08-19'), 2, 0)     
, (toDate ('2019-08-20'), 1, 0)     
, (toDate ('2019-08-20'), 2, 0)     
, (toDate ('2019-08-21'), 1, 5.6)   
, (toDate ('2019-08-21'), 2, 14)    
)
)
SELECT 
  *
, last_value (nullif (price, 0)) over (partition by id order by date)
    as prev_value
, last_value (nullif (price, 0)) over (partition by id order by date desc)
    as next_value
FROM T
ORDER BY date, id
```

| date | id | price | prev_value | next_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-08-17 | 1 | 5.0 | 5.0 | 5.0 |
| 2019-08-17 | 2 | 15.4 | 15.4 | 15.4 |
| 2019-08-18 | 1 | 0.0 | 5.0 | 5.6 |
| 2019-08-18 | 2 | 0.0 | 15.4 | 14.0 |
| 2019-08-19 | 1 | 0.0 | 5.0 | 5.6 |
| 2019-08-19 | 2 | 0.0 | 15.4 | 14.0 |
| 2019-08-20 | 1 | 0.0 | 5.0 | 5.6 |
| 2019-08-20 | 2 | 0.0 | 15.4 | 14.0 |
| 2019-08-21 | 1 | 5.6 | 5.6 | 5.6 |
| 2019-08-21 | 2 | 14.0 | 14.0 | 14.0 |